# How do I encrypt a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have been searching for ages and couldn't find a way to encrypt my javascript variable, because its used for a password:

```js
function lg() {
    var input = document.getElementById("values").value;
    if (input == pass) {
        $("nil").replaceWith($("<success>" + "Success!" + "</success>"));
        sleep(4000);        
        sleep(2000);
        window.location.replace("http://google.com");
    } 
    
    else if (input == "") {
       $("nil").replaceWith($("<error>" + "Error: No input detected!" + "</error>"));
    } 
    
    else {
        $("nil").replaceWith($("<error>" + "Incorrect Password!" + "</error>"));
    }
}

var pass="test3r"; // The one I need to encrypt
```

I don't think you would need my html or css as its just my javascript variable I need to encrypt. The variable I need to encrypt is my `var pass` one.

Comment: You can't do that. JavaSript runs in the client side, so users have full control over it. If you want password protection, you need server side code.

Comment: encryption? Either pure RSA or RSA with AES or any other strategies..

Comment: I hope that you the know tha difference between encryption and hashing

Comment: Wait so how do I do that then?

Comment: you've to see some examples on how to encrypt data using RSA or RSA with AES

Comment: btw: `sleep()` in the browser? Use `setTimeout()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your javascript is running on client side so it's not best decision to hold password in js code. And any user can just skip password check by editing code.

But if you really need this, only option I see is to use hash of password and some js library to create exact hash of user input.

For example if you will you md5 hash function (not really strong one, but there are lost of implementations in js) your password hash will look like a50bdfb74649a14c1f86b6d012f2caad

And password check will looks like if (md5(input) == pass) { ...
}

You should read about hash functions and use "salt" when hashing password to make decoding your password harder.

Comment: Yeh, it's ment to be secure so I made a PHP version of it, thanks anyway.